# Create users alias in Google API (using c#)

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-admin-sdk

This is error i am getting when i am creating alias in google admin directory for a email address.

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Entity already exists. [409]
Errors [
Message[Entity already exists.] Location[ - ] Reason[duplicate] Domain[global]
]
```

This is my Code :

I want to create alias for 
email id :  `test@test.com`

added this id to above : `aliasemailid@test.com` ===> `test@test.com`

```
var aliasesreq = service.Users.Aliases.Insert(new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.Alias 
                     {
                      AliasValue = "aliasemailid@test.com",
                   }, "test@test.com");
```

How to do ? Kindly Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an admin account so I cant test this.  But from checking the documentation on what a [Users.aliases](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases#resource) looks like I think its probably going to be something like this.

```
 string userKey = "test@test.com";
 var body = new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.Alias { PrimaryEmail = userKey, AliasValue = "aliasemailid@test.com" };
 service.Users.Aliases.Insert(body, userKey).Execute();
```

Comment: thanks DaImTo. its working. Can I know what is meant by resource id in gooogle API (i want approve/reject accounts using device management 

var mobiledevice  = service.Mobiledevices.Get(string customerID , string resourceID)

Comment: resourceId The unique ID the API service uses to identify the mobile device.  Looks like Mobiledevices.list returns a list of resources.    try looping though them https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list